# print webservice response line by line in console

Tags: java, xml, web-services

I have below webservice response from outside vendor. Need to print each line in console. Below reponse is store in response object.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<loginInformation xmlns="http://www.example.com/restapi" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <loginAccounts>
    <loginAccount>
      <accountId>117072</accountId>
      <baseUrl>https://example.net/restapi/v2</baseUrl>
      <email>abc@gmail.com</email>
    </loginAccount>
  </loginAccounts>
</loginInformation>
```

my output should be like below :

```
1.<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
2.<loginInformation xmlns="http://www.example.com/restapi" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

.
.
.
.

Comment: What are you using for doing that? There are several ways of doing it...

Comment: I just need to print them in console each line what ever response I am getting from vendor .

Comment: What's the result type? A `String` value? If so just say `System.out.println(output);`, where `output` is the variable that holds the value for the XML

Comment: Result type is string. If I print the output , I am getting whole xml printed. I need to break it with each line reading and printing out. Outpot should be like below. 1.<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
2.<loginInformation xmlns="http://www.example.com/restapi" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema

Answer (score 0):

If you parse the XML string, serialize it and then get it back, you can do that in a few steps. Try this piece of code:

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.OutputFormat;
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.XMLSerializer;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

final class XmlFormatter {
  private XmlFormatter() { }

  private static Document parse(String in) {
    final DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    try {
      final DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

      return builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(in)));
    } catch (IOException | ParserConfigurationException | SAXException e) {
      System.err.printf("Something happened here due to: %s", e);
    }
    return null;
  }

  public static String format(final String xml) {
    final Document document = XmlFormatter.parse(xml);
    final OutputFormat format = new OutputFormat(document);
    final Writer out = new StringWriter();
    final XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer(out, format);

    format.setIndenting(true);
    format.setLineWidth(120);
    format.setIndent(2);

    try {
      serializer.serialize(document);
      return out.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.printf("Something happened here...this is why: %s", e);
    }
    return null;
  }

  public static void main(final String... args) {
    System.out.printf("%s", XmlFormatter.format(/* YOUR UNFORMATTED XML */));
  }
}
```